# CI pipeline configuration for running Python unittest in docker-compose environment

Tags: python, docker-compose, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, python-unittest

I'm trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline in GitLab using docker-compose.
I have two Docker services defined in my docker-compose.yml:

- flask: hosting a Flask web application
- postgres: hosting a PostgreSQL database that is connected to the Flask web app

In the CI/CD pipeline I would like to run my unittests which need access to the database.
However, after several days of trying to set it up correctly, I still fail and I am out of ideas.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    postgres:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./dockerfile-db
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: 'xxx'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
    
    flask:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./dockerfile-flask
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        expose:
            - "5000"
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
             DB_HOST: 'postgres'
             DB_PORT: 5432
             DB_USER: 'xxx'
             DB_PW: 'xxx'
             SECRET_KEY: 'secretkey'
             APP_SETTINGS: 'config.SecureConfig'
        links:
             - postgres
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this:

```
image: docker/compose:latest

default:
  tags:
     - python

stages:
  - test

test_stage:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose up -d
    - docker-compose ps
    - docker-compose logs flask
    - docker-compose exec flask python -m unittest
```

I added the two commands "docker-compose ps" and "docker-compose logs flask" to come closer to what the issue might be. The "docker-compose ps" command outputs an empty table, but the output of the Gitlab runner does not provide further output or explanation on what might be the problem. I am currently using a Shell executor for the gitlab runner. Before I was using a docker executor and Docker in Docker (dind), but then I received a dial tcp error:

> error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/containers/[...]": dial tcp: lookup docker on XXX.XX.XX.XXX:XX: server misbehaving

with an IP that belonged to a different server in the network.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Maybe there is even an easier way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: In your .gitlab-ci.yml file, add a test stage with the following script:
yaml
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run flask python -m unittest

This script first builds the Docker images using docker-compose up --build and then runs the tests using docker-compose run flask python -m unittest

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use "docker-compose in docker" as it's fairly hard to implement in GitLab-CI when running CI/CD jobs in containers. You can use [services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/) that will allow you to run extra containers next to your job container.

In that case, you would have one Python GitLab CI Job that would install the dependencies and run the test command. That job would also instantiate one PostgreSQL service.